# Is it possible to wrap Aurelia.js validation inside the component?

Tags: validation, aurelia

The main idea wrap the quite common logic of `aurelia-validation` inside the one root component.

**Example of wrappers**

```
import { inject, bindable, containerless, NewInstance } from 'aurelia-framework';
import { ValidationController, validateTrigger, ValidationRules } from 'aurelia-validation';
import FormValidationRenderer from '../custom/form-validation-renderer';

@inject(Element, NewInstance.of(ValidationController))
export class SomeForm {
    @bindable class = "class";

    constructor(element, controller) {
        this.element = element;

        // other way it would be everywhere
        this.controller = controller;
        this.controller.addRenderer(new FormValidationRenderer());
        this.controller.validateTrigger = validateTrigger.manual;
    }

    back() {
        window.history.back();
    }

    // hide all imports to simplify usages.
    rules() {
        return ValidationRules;
    }

    setValidation(model, rules) {
        this.controller.addObject(model, rules);
    }

    submit() {
        this.element.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('submit', {}));
    }

    validate() {
        return this.controller.validate();
    }
}
```

How I'm going to use it:

**view.html**

```
 <custom-form view-model.ref="form" submit.trigger="submit()">
        <h1>Form footer test</h1>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value.bind="params.text & validate" />
 </custom-form>
```

**view.js**

```
export class View {
    params = {
        text: ''
    };

    attached() {
        this.setValidation(this.params, this.rules().ensure('text')
            .required().rules);

    }
    submit() {
        this.validate().then(err => {
            err.forEach(console.log);
        });
    }
}
```

The only one problem I'v got is the &validate tag. Inside the `validate-binding-behavior.js` that is the part of `aurelia-validation`. At line 36.

Seems it's impossible to use that attribute without `@inject` the `NewInstance.of(ValidationController)` one the view...

It may be possible to do work around on it???

```
ValidateBindingBehavior.prototype.bind = function (binding, source, rulesOrController, rules) {
        var _this = this;
        // identify the target element.
        var target = this.getTarget(binding, source);
        // locate the controller.
        var controller;
        if (rulesOrController instanceof validation_controller_1.ValidationController) {
            controller = rulesOrController;
        }
        else {
            controller = source.container.get(aurelia_dependency_injection_1.Optional.of(validation_controller_1.ValidationController));
            rules = rulesOrController;
        }
        if (controller === null) {
            throw new Error("A ValidationController has not been registered.");
        }
```

Comment: I wonder, have you got this sorted out? Infact, am looking for similar solution.

Comment: You can't do it using only the component. In fact you have to use the class to inject validationController cause it check where is it located. 

So our solution for now is: class SomeClass extend BaseForm. Where BaseForm hide the common method. Unless u have to pass validationController via super(validationController)